# Threaded commenting: how to show threads by last active first?

Tags: comments, order, threading

Hi all and happy holidays!

I have a page on which I enabled threaded commenting. At present, the comments are ordered new to old by when the thread started:

```
-Comment 3
-Comment 2
  -Comment 5
-Comment 1
  -Comment 4
```

Actually, I want the last active thread to be the first, in such a way that the listing would resemble:

```
-Comment 2
  -Comment 5
-Comment 1
  -Comment 4
-Comment 3
```

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to Settings > Discussion > Other comment settings > then look for the pull-down menu that will let you reverse the order.

As per this video:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/New-comments-first.webm

Comment: I have that  setting, and it results in the discussion ordered as described in my first code block. They are ordered reversely by thread starter, not by latest comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code in your theme’s functions.php file.

```
function wpb_reverse_comments($comments) 
 {
    return array_reverse($comments);
}   
add_filter('comments_array','wpb_reverse_comments');
```

This code uses the comments_array filter to reverse the display of comments on your WordPress site.

Comment: This basically does the same as setting the option in the backend.

Comment: You want to add option in admin panel